# How to fix "Cannot find module '@angular/core'." InjectionToken in message-format-config.d.ts (error TS2307)

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular8

I am setting up translation on my web app, more especially pluralization (taking count of spelling changes because of gender or plural form, more info here: https://github.com/lephyrus/ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler).
I am using ngx-translate and ngx-translate-messageformat (and its compiler) for the pluralization.
As soon as I installed ngx-translate-messageformat I got errors that I cannot seem to solve..

My version of Angular CLI: 8.1.0
My version of ngx-translate: 11.0.1
My version of ngx-translate-messageformat: 2.2.1
My version of ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler: 4.5.0
(all newest versions I believe)

I tried to reinstall everything, nothing changes...
I did nothing else than install messageformat module and start to implement the example from the link mentioned earlier.

Of course I included all depedencies needed (@angular/cdk and @angular/material) in package.json

The errors I get:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/fesm5/ngx-translate-core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '..\node_modules\@ngx-translate\core\fesm5'
ERROR in ../node_modules/ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler/fesm5/ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '..\node_modules\ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler\fesm5'

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

ERROR in ../node_modules/ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler/message-format-config.d.ts(1,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
```

Does someone is confronted to the same problem? I could use your help :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install `@angular/core`? via `npm i @angular/core`

Comment: Yes I did, it did updated packages tho, but still same errors...